# PHP XML DOM Document move sub-sub-nodes within sub-node

Tags: domdocument, php-7, clonenode

I have an xml like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderListResponse>
  <OrderListResponseContainer>
    <DateFrom>2018-07-01T00:00:00+00:00</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2018-07-19T00:00:00+00:00</DateTo>
    <Page>1</Page>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>4</TotalNumberOfPages>
    <Orders>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>158772</OrderID>
        <Customer>
          <Name><![CDATA[John Smith]]></Name>
          <StreetAddress><![CDATA[33, Sunset Boulevrd]]></StreetAddress>
        </Customer>
        <Delivery>
          <Name><![CDATA[John Smith]]></Name>
          <StreetAddress><![CDATA[47, Rodeo Drive]]></StreetAddress>
        </Delivery>
        <Billing>
          <Name><![CDATA[John Smith]]></Name>
          <StreetAddress><![CDATA[33, Sunset Boulevrd]]></StreetAddress>
        </Billing>
        <Payment>
          <Module>paypal</Module>
          <TransactionID/>
        </Payment>
        <DatePurchased>2018-07-01 16:30:42</DatePurchased>
        <DateLastModified>2018-07-02 21:08:28</DateLastModified>
        <CheckoutMessage><![CDATA[]]></CheckoutMessage>
        <Status>cancelled</Status>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Products>
          <Product>
            <MxpID>44237</MxpID>
            <SKU>IRF 8707TR</SKU>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
            <Price>2.46</Price>
          </Product>
        </Products>
        <Total>
          <SubTotal>7.38</SubTotal>
          <Shipping>2.7</Shipping>
          <Cod>0</Cod>
          <Insurance>0</Insurance>
          <Tax>1.62</Tax>
          <Total>11.7</Total>
        </Total>
      </Order>
      <Order>...</Order>
     </Orders>
  </OrderListResponseContainer>
</OrderListResponse>
```

and although surely there a better way to do it, 
to parse all orders I build a routine like this:

```php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmlDoc->loadXML($response);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$rootNode = $xpath->query('//OrderListResponseContainer/Orders')->item(0);
foreach($rootNode->childNodes as $node)
{
    foreach($node->childNodes as $subnode)
    {
        Process User
        foreach($subnode->childNodes as $subsubnode)
        {
            foreach($subsubnode->childNodes as $subsubsubnode)
            {
                Process Products and Sales
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **** ADDED ****
>   I use the nested loops to create one xml for each product (each xml contains details about the buyer, the item and the
>   sale) and then this xml is passed to a Stored Procedure to generate
>   the user/item/sale records: For several reason I cannot bulky import
>   Users first, then Items and then Sales but while building the sale xml
>   I need some details from the Total Node and one way to get them is to
>   move Total Node on top of the XML, but clearly within the Order Node
>   **** ADDED ****

I need to access some Total subnodes before processing Products
The only solution I found is to move Total node at the beginning, but although many attempts, I've not been able to succeed:
The idea was to clone the `totalNode` and to `appendbefore` the `OrderID` Node

The problem is that I need to work on subdocuments and select the node to clone from a node itself, while all example I found do clone the full `DocumentElement`

perhaps an easier solution can be achieved using `XSLT`?

Can suggest a solution?

Comment: Joe, I'm almost certain it is still possible to do what you want the way I have explained in my answer. However can you give a short (pseudo)-code example or a step by step written description of what exactly you are trying to achieve? It's a little vague to me right now. For instance explain more about what exactly you want to do in `Process User` and `Process Products and Sales`.

Comment: Well, difficult and not necessary to post everything since are more than 500 lines plus some sproc, but I solved as you suggested adding on top a couple of lines as you suggested. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to say about the cloning part. Perhaps you can edit your question and clarify what you mean.

However, about accessing the `Total` nodes... you could simply use XPath for this as well.

```php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmlDoc->loadXML($response);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

// first, let's fetch all <Order> elements
$orders = $xpath->query('//OrderListResponseContainer/Orders/Order');

// loop through all <Order> elements
foreach( $orders as $order ) {
  /*
    There's all sorts of ways you could convert <Total> to something useful
  */

  // Example 1.
  // fetch <Total> that is a direct child (./) of our context node (second argument) $order
  $total = $xpath->query( './Total', $order )->item( 0 );

  // then do something like
  $subTotal = $total->getElementsByTagName( 'SubTotal' )->item( 0 );
  $shipping = $total->getElementsByTagName( 'Shipping' )->item( 0 );
  // ... etc. for each child node of <Total>

  // or perhaps simply convert it to a SimpleXMLElement
  $total = simplexml_import_dom( $total );
  var_dump( $total );
  // and then access the values like this:
  $total->SubTotal;
  $total->Shipping;
  // ... etc.


  // Example 2.1
  // fetch all children of <Total> into an array
  $total = [];
  foreach( $xpath->query( './Total/*', $order ) as $totalNode ) {
    $total[ $totalNode->nodeName ] = $totalNode->textContent;
  }
  var_dump( $total );

  // Example 2.2
  // fetch all children of <Total> into a stdClass object
  $total = new \stdClass;
  foreach( $xpath->query( './Total/*', $order ) as $totalNode ) {
    $total->{ $totalNode->nodeName } = $totalNode->textContent;
  }
  var_dump( $total );

  /*
    Now, after this you can create and process the Customer and Products data
    in a similar fashion as I've shown how to process the Total data above
  */
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, I just added a simple explanation. Beside this yes, I could access to Total Node via xPath, although it will make it twice... 
Will make some tests.. thanks